# How to integrate WebSphere Application Server 7 into Rational Software Architect?

Tags: eclipse, websphere, websphere-7

In Rational Software Architect (RSA), how do I add WebSphere Application Server 7 (WAS7) as a Server? As you can see in the screen shot, WAS7 is not an option. How do I add it? Thank you.

I am running Rational Software Architect for WebSphere Software (RSA) Version 8.5.1. I have installed WAS7 using the installer available in the was.7000.wasdev.nocharge.windows.amd64 package.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Install WAS 7 Server Adapter**

1. Open IBM Installation Manager.
2. Click Modify Icon
3. Under "Modify Packages" Screen 1; Click Next
4. Under "Modify Packages" Screen 2; Click Next
5. scroll to "Server tools"; select WebSphere Application Server 7.0.
6. Proceed to finish modification.

Now WAS 7 should be an option when adding a new server.

[image: IBM Installation Manager main screen]

[image: Modify Packages Screen 1]

[image: Modify Packages Screen 2 - Language]

[image: Choose WebSphere Application Server 7.0]

[image: Add new Server instance]

Answer (score 1):

During RSA installation you might not installed support for WAS v7.
Check if you have following folder: `%RSA_HOME%\runtimes\base_v7_stub`.
If not you might need to rerun Installation manager and modify RSA to include stub for WAS v7.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I checked that directory and I do have base_v7_stub. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hmm.. strange. Maybe try adding server via Preferences > Server > Runtime Environments and try 'Add...' there. Maybe you will be able to see WAS v7.

Comment: I agree this is unusual. In fact, that is the screen shot that is shown above. That is the exact steps I took attempting to get the Runtime Environment setup. Sorry I didnt mention that.